# Got SSL connection reset by peer exception when sending POST request with C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ssl, dotnet-httpclient, splunk

I am a C# beginner, I was facing a weird issue when posting request to the Splunk collector instance of internal corporate network.
I know there are a lot of solutions, but I have tried I can do.

I am using HttpClient in a simple class and it is used to send a post request to submit metric json data to Splunk collector.

But in the line "http.PostAsync(ApiUrl, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);", the application stuck for a long time(>10s) and eventually reported the error, "**The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception., inner exception, Unable to read data from the transport connection:                                                                 Connection reset by peer.**"

It's really weird, because I thought I have already bypassed the SSL validation within the Splunk constructor.

After two more days troubleshooting, I have no idea why I got this error, the Token/API key/data I used/planned to send are correct definitely and I can directly post the data via Postman and curl, also, I can use the PostAsync method in my code to visit the open post api, like https://httpbin.org/post, etc.

The Splunk collector api is like https://(address):(port)/services/collector/event, it is hosted within our internal network, and the code I pasted to here is an api, I hosted and ran in a linux VM, in somewhere of my code will call the Submit() method to send the data I collected in the splunkEvent object.

Below are some conditions for the HttpHandler instance I have tried, but no one worked...
Just for your reference.

1. handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
2. handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
3. handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
4. handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true;

I use ASP.Net Core 3.1 to build my app.

I am on the edge of drowning, will be really really appreciate if you provide me the solution.

```
public class Splunk
{
        private string ApiUrl { get; set; }
        private string ApiKey { get; set; }
        private HttpClient http;
        public Splunk()
        {
            using (var config = Subsystem.RuntimeContext.getSingletonInstance())
            {
                ApiUrl = config.getItemValue("SYSTEM", "SPLUNK", "COLLECTOR");
                ApiKey = config.getItemValue("SYSTEM", "SPLUNK", "TOKEN");
            }
            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => true;
            http = new HttpClient(handler);
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", $"Splunk {ApiKey}");
        }
        
        public virtual bool Submit(SplunkEvent splunkEvent)
        {
            
            var setting = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                {
                    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
                }
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(splunkEvent, setting);

            try
            {
                http.PostAsync(ApiUrl, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.Output(Verbosity.ERROR, $"Error Msg, {e.Message}, inner exception, {e.InnerException.Message}");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: The error doesn't have to be about TLS. It can also be that the Splunk server rejects your client IP. Have you tried performing a request with Insomnia, Postman or another HTTP/REST client?

Comment: Yes, the Postman worked as expected with same data/apikey/token...
I got 200 status code and my data could be found on the Splunk.  
I understand your concern, but I directly ran the curl post command in the same linux VM, it worked.

Comment: Why are you using Core 3.1?  TLS didn't worked well on old Core versions and many issues have to fixed with newer versions of Core.  TLS is sent before the HTTP Request is sent to establish an encryption key using a certificate. If TLS failed the Request was never sent so connection didn't complete.  Your error is a timeout which just indicates the connection didn't complete (probably TLS, not definite). The certificate contains a key and the encryption mode.  Older versions of Net/Core did not support every certificate.  Starting with Net 4.7.2 TLS is now done with OS instead of Net/Core.

Comment: But if I have bypassed the SSL validation in theory, the condition you mentioned should not be happened, right? I know the version is matter, but we couldn't update the dotnet version easily.

Comment: You could be having a Proxy issue and turning off the proxy may solve issue.  Postman may have the proxy disabled or doing TLS in OpenSSL instead of OS or Net/Core.  The default HTTP headers are different in Postman than c#.  Often connection issues are due to default header wrong or missing.  All we really know right now is the connection didn't complete and a timeout printed an error message.  It may not be TLS, but it is a possible reason.

Comment: Hi weng, I tried to remove the proxy with http.Proxy = null, still didn't work.
Also I clean the defaultheaders with clear() method, and then directly set the header into httpclient instance, unworkable also.

Comment: Or you might have a TLS cipher mismatch. Watch the connection in Wireshark and show us what the Server Hello and Client Hello look like. What version of Windows and .NET are you on? Exact build numbers please

Comment: No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 6095 bytes and written 415 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
  -----above is the info from using openssl s_client -connect  command for slunk collector

Comment: this one is the API host ---->

CONNECTED(00000003)
140071662217104:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:794:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 289 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated

Comment: Sorry I can't use Wireshark directly, it has been blocked in our network.

Comment: Below is the information about my app, build engine .Net core 16.4.0+e901037fe.

Comment: The build engine version is not useful, I need the Windows version and .NET version of the server running the application. A Wireshark trace would tell you what is going wrong with the handshake.